# CSS image transparancy and background color

Tags: html, css

I cant get the following working:

```
.smoke{background-image:url('../img/base/bg_smoke.png'); }
.blue{background-color:#1C3F95;}
```

The idea is that with a different color class I can change the background color behind the transparant image.

```
<div class="blue smoke"></div>
<div class="red smoke"></div>
```

But when I am using this code the only thing that shows is the background image with transparancy to white, how do I get the color on the background? Is this even possible?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You will need to specify both the `background-image` and the `background-color` using the `background` property of CSS. Please try using this CSS:

```
.blue.smoke{
     background: url('../img/base/bg_smoke.png'), #1C3F95; 
}
```

Comment: This is what I am trying to avoid, I know this works but I do not want to get a giant list redefining the image and the color as two different statements in the css

Comment: Ah nevermind, my code works... the image just was not transparant.. sorry for wasting your  time, here have a +1